# Orbeon section in wizard view unclickable after setting visibility=true at runtime

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have a yes/no fields that controls whether the next 3 sections are visible (relevant) or not. It works fine, but as soon as the visibility state is changed at runtime, the sections cannot be clicked anymore in wizard view! I also cannot navigate to them using the prev/next buttons at the bottom. Is this a bug?

I defined rules for all sections that have a conditional visibility state:

```
relevant="$control-1 eq true()"
```

Is there another way i could do this, maybe as a "global" XPath expression?

[Demo](http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/qwe/qwe/new)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug. We fixed a very similar one with [#3547](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3547), but I entered a new bug since this is failing again, see [#3610](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3610). Please follow-up there.

Comment: The bug is fixed for 2018.1, it turns out.